# Host file set, ping goes 127.0.0.1, but in browser URL still goes out to web?

Tags: iis-7, localhost

Having some issues running my code local.

I have host file setup like this:

127.0.0.1 ryan.local.myappname.com

if I ping that URL it kicks back from 127...

but if I browse there in firefox or IE it takes me to an old version of the site that is currently live instead of taking me to the local one...

I am running Windows 7

Any ideas?

NOTE: firefox set to no proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run the following from an elevated command-prompt:

```
IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS
```

Then restart your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I know Windows XP keeps it's own DNS cache distinct from the browser's cache.  Not sure if Windows 7 does as well, but you can try running

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser's local resolver cache.